# IE8, IE9 with Chrome Frame Crashing when a new Window is Opened

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, frame

This page exists as a file in an ASP.NET application with target framework 3.5.

I've been experiencing an error on my site (first reported yesterday) that has to do with users having Chrome Frame installed on IE8 or IE9 and them clicking on a link to Open a New Window.  The Child page opens up, but when the Child Window is closed (or sometimes before), the Parent Window Crashes.  (The screen is completely grey).

Test code which replicates this issue is below, but I have no idea what is occurring or how to resolve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="open-link">Hi</button>

    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("open-link");
        a.addEventListener("click", function () {
            window.open("http://google.com", "Browser");
        }, false); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal anchor link? O_o

Comment: The anchor link needs to use a dynamic link, but I assume it is worth a try.

Comment: if It's generated dynamically, set that as a variable on the page then reference it in the anchor.

Comment: It looks like it is something related to ASP.NET and Chrome Frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing the same issue while on a different platform, so it is not an ASP.net.  If you are using Chrome Frame, use window.open to open another window, then close that window, it crashes the remaining tab/window.  If your window being opened is outside of the same-domain policy then it crashes the opening tab on opening instead of on close.

I do not have a workaround or solution yet, will post if I find one.

Comment: I found a really weird hack that fixes it... 

What I did, was instantiate an instance of jQuery UI's autocomplete on an HTML element that i placed off the screen and window.open no longer seems to crash IE...  

I'll let you know if I find a better solution.  * I also changed my .html page to a .aspx......

Comment: Woah, that is a really strange hack. I'll experiment with similar things this morning to see what I can get working.

Comment: Even stranger, I am having this same issue when I just click a link with a target="_blank" attribute, apparently. It's pretty broken. :-/

Comment: I opened a bug, no idea if they are responsive: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173123

Comment: This appears to have been fixed last friday: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171877

Answer (score 1):

Can use a normal anchor link, and you said it's generated dynamically.

Set dynamic url to a variable either in  tags in view or global namespace.

```
var dynamicUrl = {{myUrl}},
    urlTitle = {{myUrl.title}}; // Or whatever construct is generating.
```

HTML

```
<a href="dynamicUrl" target="_blank" alt="urlTitle">Hi</a>
```

Comment: Does that really work? Doesn't that just link to the literal url "dyanmicUrl" (not the value of that variable)?

Comment: The {{}} are to insert where his URL is being generated dynamically. Angularjs, ExpressionEngine & Handlebars (I think) use these {{}}, but if you're using a different CMS or templating language it would be the same.

Comment: Ahh, you mean in the actual href. Uh, good point. Might have to do some attr() or setting the elements href to that dynamicUrl var.